Angular18 : ngx-owl-carousel-o does not rendering correctly
I am using ngx-owl-carousel-o version 18 with Angular18. I am trying to use 2  owl-carousel into single row. But it does not rendering as expected. Owl corousel displaying only one item. Owl-carousel issue
Here is my code sample:
Parentcomponent.html :
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 suppliers-part separator">
            <app-sellers [datacount]=9 />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 buyers-part">
            <app-buyers [datacount]=9 />
        </div>
    </div>

sellerscomponent.html:
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
    <ng-template carouselSlide *ngFor="let seller of sellers" [id]="seller.id">
        <div class="product-item bg-light">
            <div class="product-img">
                <div class="sp-onimg">
                    <div class="favorite">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <p>
                                <i class="fa fa-heart" title="Add to my favorite list"></i>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="favorite">
                        <a title="Add to my contacts" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <p><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/supplier4.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-detail">
                <p>{{ seller.name }}</p>
                <div class="d-flex mt-2">
                    <a href="" class="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login to View</a>
                    <p class="india" style="margin-left: auto;"><img src="img/india2.png"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</owl-carousel-o>

sellerscomponent.ts code for owl corousel:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sellers',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CarouselModule],
  templateUrl: './sellers.component.html',
  styleUrl: './sellers.component.css'
})
export class SellersComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
  @Input() datacount: any = 0;
  sellers: any;
  customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: false,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    navText: ['<', '>'],
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 1
      },
      740: {
        items: 3
      },
      940: {
        items: 3
      },
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getseller(this.datacount).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response.status == 'success') {
        this.sellers = response.data;
      }
      // console.log(this.sellers);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
}


I created same code for buyerscomponent. It supposed to display 3 Items at the slider area. But it does not working as expected.

please share working example on stackblitz, steps to replicate the issue and desired output from the stackblitz

I have a code example on StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tqxc5hfn) that works as expected. However, my local code isn't working the same way. Could the issue be related to slow file loading on my local environment?

check your CSS, compare with the stackblitz and your local code, you will find that it expands the container element, is my guess

I discovered the issue! The carousel view is being loaded before the data is fully loaded. Thanks you  for your help.
